# technical term for "形容動詞{けいようどうし} + にする"?

Tags: grammar, words

A subset of Japanese nouns is the サ変名詞{へんめいし} nouns such as:

> 勉強{べんきょう}する
>   運転{うんてん}する
>   残業{ざんぎょう}する

A subset of 形容動詞 words can be appended with "にする" such as:

> 静{しず}かにする
>   大切{たいせつ}にする
>   無理{むり}にする

What is the English, and Japanese, technical grammar term for this class of 形容動詞 words?

Comment: I've been trying to think of one, but as far as I can tell, all 形容動詞 work with 「〜にする」. Do you have one in mind that doesn't work?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I was thinking that these do not make sense (to me at least): "素直にする", "便利にする", "下手にする". Each could take "~になる", but not "~にする"?? I don't know. I am just guessing... I am realizing I need to stop making assumptions and guessing so much on stackexchange. :-)

Comment: 静かにする(behave quietly = be quite) and 無理をする (excessively do = overwork) are the the Japanese way to change an adjective to a verb. It works for 形容詞 too, e.g., 早くしろ(quickly do = be quick/hurry up). 大切にする may be consider as 連語 (may be translated as _phrasal verbs_?). Other examples are 楽しみにする, 大事にする, etc. する can often be replaced by 思う or 扱う.

Comment: I made a mistake, I typed 無理にする but I actually meant 無理をする. 無理に just means 無理やり, is a normal adverb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of Japanese as 国語 (a national language), it's `連用形 of 形容動詞 + する`. But from the point of view of "Japanese as a second/foreign language", I think it's mostly considered to be `辞書形 of な形容詞 + にする`.

形容動詞 are very controversial. Most Japanese as a second/foreign language textbooks call them な形容詞 (na-adjectives), but *Japanese: The Spoken Language* for example calls them な名詞 (na nominals). There are many theories but the strongest one I've heard is that 綺麗な or those words called 形容動詞 in 国語 have originated from `noun + verbal auxiliary なり`. なり meant (1) assertion and (2) existence.